# Does anyone knows how to create a DenseVector[Double] using Breeze library in scala

Tags: json, scala, json4s, scala-breeze

I want to create data that have a form of List[DenseVector[Double]] using scala and Breeze library. The initial data are loaded with json4s, so they have a form of List(Jarray(JDouble) does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this code:

```
  list
    .map { case JArray(list) => list.map { case JDouble(v) => v } }
    .map(el => DenseVector(el))
```

Comment: thank you, I found out by using  `.map(x=>x.children).map(x=>DenseVector(x.map(y=>y.extract[Double]):_*)) `